# How sort a multi value array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this multi value array which I want to sort

```
Array(
    [0] => word1 131
    [1] => word2 3
    [2] => word3 5
    [3] => word4 4
    [4] => word5 16
    [5] => word6 29
)
```

How do I sort it using the number value on the right so the result will be like this.

```
Array(
    [0] => word2 3
    [1] => word4 4
    [2] => word3 5
    [3] => word5 16
    [4] => word6 29
    [5] => word1 131
)
```

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and create a callback function that parses the string and sorts the data.

```
function usort_callback($a, $b)
{
  $a = preg_replace('/^.+\s(\d+)$/', '$1', $a);
  $b = preg_replace('/^.+\s(\d+)$/', '$1', $b);

  return ( intval($a) < intval($b) ) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, 'usort_callback');
```

Comment: This is working great man! Thank you very much! I just wasted hours without knowing usort function lol

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use explode or str_split() to isolate the number on the right, sort using array_sort() or one of the related functions, and reassemble the array.

Answer (score 0):

Define a comparison function and use usort. In your comparison function you can use str_split or pregmatch to get interesting parts of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usort` and users function like this:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a = (int)substr(strstr($a, ' '), 1); 
    $b = (int)substr(strstr($b, ' '), 1);   
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$array = array(
    'word1 131',
    'word2 3',
    'word3 5',
    'word4 4',
    'word5 16',
    'word6 29'
);

usort($array, "cmp");

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: this is great too with invoking regex engine! thanks. Sorry can't vote up yet :(